# How to add title and date only to blog posts on word press

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I am trying to display the title and post date on the blog posts only. I couldn't find any answers when Googling and Binging. Currently no matter the page it is displaying the title to the page and the date it was made on.

Here is the index code I am using:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main"><br><br>
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<br> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<div id="delimiter">
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I know that it is calling the title on every page and the phrase "Posted on". I would like to know how to get it to where it will only display those on my blog posts.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to edit the [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) related to the respective pages.

In your current code, you can check the post type of the current post within the loop. Then display the title and date conditionally.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main"><br><br>
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $postType = get_post_type();

if($postType == 'post'){ ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>

<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>

<?php if($postType == 'post'){ ?>
<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<?php } ?>

<br> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<div id="delimiter">
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: How do you use templates for the blog page? I don't see an option for templates on the blog page.

Comment: Do you mean for a single blog page (post actually) or blog archive page?